# Iterate through a column to create another column based on logic using single line code

Tags: python

`movies['Has Bill Seen It']=[True for d['Movie Title'] == 'Titanic' else False]`

This is giving this error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-67-81210f98cc37>", line 1
    movies['Has Bill Seen It']=[True for d['Movie Title']=='Titanic' else False]
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I think `movies['Has Bill Seen It']= d['Movie Title'] == 'Titanic' ` works, or `movies['Has Bill Seen It']= [True if x == 'Titanic' else False for x in d['Movie Title']]`

Comment: Thank You It works.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a common use-case in pandas and, as such, it can be done quite easily.

```py
movies["Has Bill Seen It"] = d["Movie Title"] == "Titanic"
```

And, in case you want all the data, you could simply do:

```py
d[ d["Movie Title"] == "Titanic" ]
```